# Issues configuring Fabric for Twitter API within Xcode project

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I am having issues sending the `[Fabric with:@[TwitterKit]]` message after importing the `TwitterKit.h` and `Fabric.h` libraries through Fabric's multi-step process. Specifically, the error states *Use of Undeclared Identifier 'TwitterKit'; did you mean 'Twitter'?* Any suggestions and solutions are greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Mikal

Comment: Do you make this import ?
 #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>